# Swift Array of strings to UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFString>>!

Tags: swift3, cfstring, unsafemutablepointer, diskarbitration

I am trying to call [DADiskMountWithArguments](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/diskarbitration/1492714-dadiskmountwitharguments?language=objc) using Swift.

```swift
swiftfunc DADiskMountWithArguments(_ disk: DADisk, _ path: CFURL?, _ options: DADiskMountOptions, _ callback: DADiskMountCallback?, _ context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, _ arguments: UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFString>>!)
```

My issue is getting from a Swift array of strings, to an **UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFString>>!** which is the expected argument input format.

From the docs:

**arguments**
  *The null-terminated list of mount options to pass to /sbin/mount -o.*

In Objective-C I accomplished the same call by creating the arguments value like this:

```c
NSArray *args = @[
            @"rdonly",
            @"noowners",
            @"nobrowse",
            @"-j",
        ];

CFStringRef *argv = calloc(args.count + 1, sizeof(CFStringRef));
CFArrayGetValues((__bridge CFArrayRef)args, CFRangeMake(0, (CFIndex)args.count), (const void **)argv);

DADiskMountWithArguments((DADiskRef)_disk, (__bridge CFURLRef)url, kDADiskMountOptionDefault, DiskMountCallback, (__bridge void *)(self), (CFStringRef *)argv);
```

But I have not successfully ported this method to Swift. And I haven't found a way to get the argument array into memory and getting the correct pointer to it either.

Things I've tried:

1. Trying to use CFArrayGetValues:

```swift
// Example arguments array
let arguments = ["rdonly", "noowners", "nobrowse", "-j"]

// Create an UnsafeMutableRawPointer and allocate the correct string size
let argsUnsafeMutableRawPointer = calloc(arguments.count + 1, MemoryLayout<CFString>.size)

// Convert the Mutable pointer to an Immutable one
let argsUnsafeRawPointer: UnsafeRawPointer? = UnsafeRawPointer.init(argsUnsafeMutableRawPointer)

// CFArrayGetValues expects an UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeRawPointer?>. I have an UnsafeRawPointer, but can't get it into an UnsafeMutablePointer<T>.
let argsUnsafeMutablePointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeRawPointer?>! = ?

// Call CFArrayGetValues
CFArrayGetValues(arguments as CFArray, CFRangeMake(0, CFIndex(arguments.count)), argsUnsafeMutablePointer)

// Call DADiskMountWithArguments
DADiskMountWithArguments(self.diskRef, url, DADiskMountOptions(kDADiskMountOptionDefault), diskMountCallback, nil, ?)
```

Should I use an Opaque pointer to bridge from UnsafeRawPointer to UnsafeMutablePointer?

2. Trying to create the Array of c strings (char **) without CFArrayGetValues. But I don't really know how I would go about doing that?

```swift
// Example arguments array
let arguments = ["rdonly", "noowners", "nobrowse", "-j"]

// Create an Unmanaged<CFString> from the arguments array
let argsUnmanagedCFString: Unmanaged<CFString> = ?

// Create an UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFString>>! from the argsUnmanagedCFString
let argsUnsafeMutablePointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFString>>! = ?

// Call DADiskMountWithArguments
DADiskMountWithArguments(self.diskRef, url, DADiskMountOptions(kDADiskMountOptionDefault), diskMountCallback, nil, argsUnsafeMutablePointer)
```

Is it again Opaque pointers that is the key to bridging the different types, or am I looking at this the wrong way?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Interesting question. `var args = ["rdonly", "noowners", "nobrowse", "-j"].map { Unmanaged.passRetained($0 as CFString) }` will create `[Unmanaged<CFString>]`, which you can then pass as `UnsafeMutablePointer` with `DADiskMountWithArguments(..., &args)`. (Remember to release those later.) I'm just unclear how to create null terminated rendition, though.

Comment: I would consider this a bug, as `Unmanaged` only deals with non-nil pointers. You'll have to hack around the type-system in order to make it work. Really the parameter should be of type `UnsafeMutablePointer<CFString?>?`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will bridge this to Objective-C for now then, but it should be doable in Swift. And if it's a bug I should probably report it to get it fixed, because the all the other similar null terminated c arrays I've seen that looks like this have all been marked optional it the type.